# concurrency Control for inserting records based on previous transaction

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I am having a situation in which i have to make the entries from TableA to TableB such that i need to counter-balance the entries.
For example: 
TableA
ID    Name
1   A
2   B
3   C
if no entries in TableB of Table for any user,i will add entries in 
TableA for User1 As

```
ID  TableA_ID   UserID
1       1       1
2       2       1   
3       3       1
```

For anther user say User2, i need to check for the entries of lastUser and find out which entry made first. Entry which made first will be made at last for next user. As

```
ID    TableA_ID   UserID
1         1         1
2         2         1   
3         3         1
4         2         2
5         3         2   
6         1         2
```

Similiar for next user enteries will be

```
7         3         3
8         1         3   
9         2         3
```

Problem here is that all users may request at the same time and i need to implement locking mechanism to handle it. For any user's request, i need to find the entries for last user. The table must be locked until user makes entries in tableB. In Short i want to control the concurrency. Please suggest how to implement it. It would be better if it does not effect the entries from TableC to TableB.